# C++ STL containers are slow when used as simple buffers (I did a benchmark)?

Tags: c++, stl

I've always assumed that C++ code is generally on par with C code in terms of efficiency, if not better (Ex: std::sort beats qsort due to comparator inlining). It is also widely accepted that if a dynamic memory buffer is necessary std::vector would be a reasonable first choice.

Lately I've implemented a benchmark to get the hard data and got surprising results. Basically appending to a vector (or a string) in a tight loop is *relatively slow*.

Please enlighten me if it is possible to make it faster!

See below for the bloody details on the benchmark.

Certainly one option would be to go for custom containers. I desperately want to avoid this route as long as possible for obvious reasons (consistency in the code plus the overhead of converting between incompatible representations of the same thing, say std::string and a custom_string).

About the [benchmark](https://github.com/mejedi/fix-utf8).

There is an input buffer and the output buffer. If an input byte passes the validation it is transferred to output as is, otherwize it is encoded and the resulting 3 bytes are transferred (some sort of escaping here). The algorithm being implemented is UTF-8 validation.

Basically here is the [code](https://github.com/mejedi/fix-utf8/blob/master/src/fix_utf8.cc#L26):

```
// Templated Sink allows us to play with different methods for building
// the output to estimate the relative efficiency of various approaches
// (ex: a large buffer with no bounds checking vs. std::string).
template <typename Sink>
const unsigned char *
fix_utf8_engine(Sink &sink,
                const unsigned char *i, const unsigned char *end)
{
    while (i < end) {

        // for sinks with limited capacity
        if (!sink.check_capacity())
            return i;

        switch (i[0]) {

            case 0x00 ... 0x7f:
                // 1-byte UTF-8 sequence
                sink.template write<1>(i);
                i += 1;
                continue;

...
```

I've implemented different variations of fix_utf8, including the one writing to a preallocated "infinite" buffer (no bounds checking or growing, the **baseline**), the one producing results in a dynamically growing malloc-ed buffer (**malloc**), the one producing std::string (**string**) and the one producing std::vector (**vector**).

Here are the results (Ivy Bridge Core i7 laptop, clang-600.0.56 -O3) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)):

```
             ASCII       Unicode     Unicode     Unicode     Unicode     Unicode     Random
                         small       full        evil mix    evil short  evil long

baseline     0.01307     0.01816     0.01912     0.01909     0.03104     0.03781     0.06127
malloc       0.01798     0.02068     0.02116     0.02095     0.03918     0.04684     0.06909
string       0.02791     0.03045     0.02575     0.02520     0.07871     0.11513     0.09580
vector       0.06210     0.04925     0.04017     0.04027     0.10103     0.15159     0.12871
```

Different columns are for different kinds of randomly generated input (**Unicode small** — limited range up to 2 bytes of the resulting UTF-8, **evil mix** — all kinds of broken UTF-8 data interspersed with normal data, **evil short/long** — all UTF-8 sequences are truncated by 1 byte).

These result clearly demonstrate that **string** and **vector** variants are considerably slower on at least two very important use cases — **ASCII** and **Unicode (small)**.

Any help for improving these results is greately appreciated!

Comment: No mention of compiler(s) used, no mention whether the build being used are optimized builds (as opposed to debug builds), etc.  A lot of numbers, but the information that is sorely needed is missing.

Comment: Any chance you can do a little to narrow down the code that's really relevant to the question at hand? I glanced through the repo you linked, but a lot of the code seems irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: A search for `std_vector_sink` finds the critical code

Comment: @MooingDuck: My point was more to create something we can compile, that still eliminates the parts irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: I don't see any containers in your question. Abstract out the irrelevant gubbins _for us_ rather than expecting us to do it _for you_.

Comment: Another issue: the `malloc_sink` does not handle `realloc` failure.

Comment: Another issue: you'll note you do a reserve, but it isn't quite enough room for every case.  Every `write_bad` writes more than one byte out for every byte in.  It should be enough room for the cases with no `write_bad` (ie, no 'evil'?)

Comment: You do branch prediction for the `malloc_sync` manually.  Have you tried `-fprofile-arcs` to train the `vector`/`string` cases?  Also, can you write a `naive_malloc` that does not use `realloc`, but instead does a separate `malloc` and does a `memcpy` of the old buffer, then `free`s it?  I don't think `vector` can exploit a `realloc` based strategy, and I doubt `string` can: it might prove illuminating.

Comment: `insert( ... )` can sometimes be really suboptimal for `vector`, as some (in my opinion, poor-quality) implementations do conservative allocations there.  Try a `vector` solution with manual capacity management (it can just check `capacity() >= size()+n`).  Another approach to squeezing performance (or isolating where the problem might be) out of `vector` is to give the `vector` a non-initializing allocator, do a `resize` and then write over the new bytes (using `data()+a, data()+b`)

Comment: The benchmark might be flawed - it is ignoring any result.

Comment: @Yakk I have tried removing the branch prediction from the `malloc` case, removing the manual loop unrolling, replaced `realloc` with `malloc`+`memcpy`+`free`. I also shuffled the order of tests. Timings didn't change much. (I'm also computing the length of the string after `fix_utf8` to get side-effects.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my particular environment the following helped.

The original code working with std::string was slow because of the many code pathes ending with a distinct call to insert(). Insert was partially inlined resulting in a massive code bloat (though not inlining at all would be even worse).

The solution that worked was to abandon insert() and to render output using pointers. Once the output pointer catched up with the output buffer end pointer, we determine the output offset within the string, increase string size by a fixed amount and update pointers.

```
std::string output;
char *opos; // output pos
char *end_obuf;

while (...) {

   if (opos + 6 > end_obuf) { // 6 bytes produced per iteration or less
      output.resize(s.size() + 128);
      // reinit opos, end_obuf pointers
      ...
   }

   // processing
   ...
}
```

It is important to never write past the string end since there is no legal way to make that data part of the string (data past the end is erased once the string grows, at least with default allocator).

Hence we are actually resizing the string here (intentionally using resize() instead of reserve()).

Growing by a fixed amount is ok; actually the standard requires the buffer to grow exponentially when the content grows linearly. The particular amount (128) is a tradeoff: growing too much is bad since we are going to zero-initialize that many bytes. Growing too little is also bad since we don't want to execute resize code too often.

To summarize many calls to insert() were replaced with the single call to resize() making the generated code more lean. Resize branch is executed infrequently hence amortizing the cost across several loop iterations.

A few closing remarks:

1. Comparing STL allocator with realloc was indeed unfair. Realloc can often resize the buffer without making a copy. STL allocator always makes a complete copy due to OOP concerns.

   Feature request: it would be nice if STL used realloc for POD types by default.

   "Pessimizing" malloc made the results virtually identical (about 20% of the original difference in the performance were for this sole reason).
2. It was interesting to see if the dynamic reallocation of the string buffer imposes that much of the performance overhead. Over-reserving plus pessimizing malloc was not enough to close the gap. In this particular problem the data processing speed was more important (note: string size is 8MiB here, with smaller strings the results may change.)
3. Profile-guided optimization (-fprofile-generate/-fprofile-use) allows to gain another 5-10% consistently, many thanks for this option.

Comment: There's a big difference between `resize()` and `reserve()`.  You're likely to have an incorrectly sized string in this code.

Comment: Yes, obviously the size is adjusted once the processing completes.

Comment: That's also a source of your performance problems.  You said the reason you're only growing by 128 bytes is the string was zero-initializing all the bytes.  If you use `reserve()` it allocates the memory and doesn't modify the values.

Comment: The current variant seams ok performance-wize (figures are very close to the variant with manual buffer management). Thank you very much but I am perfectly aware of what reserve does — actually I've mentioned the reasons for not using it above ("It is important to never write past the string end since there is no legal way to make that data part of the string").

Comment: `insert()` will ensure that you don't write past the end.  That's what was causing the performance problems in the first place. :-)

Comment: I sort of said the same very thing explicitly (mentioning the generated assembly code, etc.) The trick is that the code is still valid though outright ugly:) Still wondering how to do it in a clean way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct.  Using the vector or string like that is indeed slow.  Basically every time you append you're appending to the end of the container, you're potentially asking the container to reallocate a new buffer, copy the data over to the new buffer, and delete the old buffer.

You can improve the results in two ways.  First, if you know the size you can use the `reserve()` method.   Second, if you're using a vector, you can switch to a `deque`, which is what I use when I don't have a good feeling for the size I want.  That will work better in this use case.  That's because deque doesn't reallocate memory -- it grows gracefully by pages.  There's a trade-off on access for that flexibility (one level of indirection), but since you're only inserting right now it shouldn't be applicable.

One comment claims that you reserve enough, but that's not true.  You can write more than you read. I'd still use a similar growth strategy to the malloc strategy in check_capacity().  That's going to give you the best apples to apples comparison.

Here is a template version that should implement check_capacity() correctly and work for all STL containers (including deque).  Use this instead of std_vector_sink and std_string_sink.

```
// Write output to a container
template < typename CONTAINER >
struct std_sink
{
    CONTAINER &v_;
    std_sink(CONTAINER &v): v_(v) {}
    bool check_capacity() { 
        if (v_.capacity() - v_.size() <= 8) {
            v_.reserve(v_.size() + (v_.size() / 2));
        }
        return true;
    }
    template<size_t n> void write(const unsigned char *p) {
        v_.insert(v_.end(), p, p+n);
    }
    void write_bad(const unsigned char *p) {
        unsigned char esc[] = {
            utf8b_1(*p),
            utf8b_2(*p),
            utf8b_3(*p)
        };
        v_.insert(v_.end(), esc, esc + 3);
    }
};
```

Also, try it with deque:

```
std_sink< std::deque< unsigned char> > sink(result);
```

Comment: Not really every time, rather now and then. In the end you will likely need *O(log(finalsize))* reallocations, but that depends on your stdlibs implementation.

Comment: Yep.  I caught that when I read my answer and changed it to "potentially asking". :-)  However, when you're in a tight loop, you hit that quite often.  It's all implementation dependent, but it usually sucks the wind out of your sails once you hit it!

Comment: If you read the linked source, the `malloc` case also uses an exponential reallocation strategy (with a 1.5 power).

Comment: ... and looking at the source, all buffers are preallocated to be "big enough", and contain reallocation code (except the baseline "infinite buffer")

Comment: It's not always "big enough" (as you noted later on), nor does it use the same reallocation strategy as the malloc solution.  Updated my answer with a template version that should work on all STL container and will give apples to apples comparison on reallocation.

Comment: I believe the check_capacity() part is entirely unnecessary since insert already bears this logic.

Comment: @NickZavaritsky We only know that insert will reallocate memory.  We don't know how, and if it's not efficient then performance will suffer.  Play around with different implementations and see what happens.

Comment: @Jason Surely insert will reallocate memory if it runs out of the reserve, and the standard actually mandates the new capacity to be K times the old capacity (i.e. exponential growth). I think I've got your point — are you enforcing the particular K(=1.5) here?

Comment: @Nick so the standard effectively mandates exponential growth **at some points** by demanding amortized linear performance.  But I am unaware of a general statement that demands exponential growth in general.  Examine the actual method you are calling that you are expecting to cause the container to grow: does it guarantee amortized linear cost?

Answer (score 1):

They're fast when you understand how to use them.  My guess is you're continuously calling vector.push_back(value), which is going to reallocate a new buffer every time it runs out memory (generally it doubles its allocation each time you hit the limit).  You want to do a vector.reserve(reasonableCapacity) first.

Comment: His code is actually worse than using `push_back` for each character.